# Putting JSON data from API to select field in html

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I am requesting get from an API and it throws me this

[image]

how do I put it inside an html select field using jquery ajax?

I would like it to become something like this:

```
<select>
     <option>Child (between 3 - 12)</option>
     <option>Transport or Direct ticket</option>
     <option>Baby (3 and under free)</option>
     <option>Senior Price (60+ years)</option>
     <option>Child (between 3 - 12)</option>
     <option>Adult</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Parse the json, cycle over the `data` array, generate elements. What part are you having problems with?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I don't know how to parse it.

Comment: Have you tried googling "parse json javascript"? Because I see a lot of results there.

Comment: Here, as an example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = '{"data": [{"pricebook_item": ""}, {"pricebook_item": ""}]}';
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

var select = '<select>';

for (var i in jsonData) {
   select += '<option value="' + jsonData[i].item + '">' + jsonData[i].item + '</option>';
}
select += '</select>';
$("#selector").html(select);
```

This code will loop throw the JSON array and generate the HTML select and insert it into the element with `selector` id.

Comment: There's no json in your code. In the comments OP said they have trouble parsing the JSON, which is the only thing your answer doesn't cover.

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(json);//where json is the JSON data.

var selectHTML = '<select>';
for(i=0;i<jsonData['pricebook_item'].length;i++){
     selectHTML+= '<option value="' + jsonData['pricebook_item'][i] + '">' + jsonData['pricebook_item'][i] + '</option>';
    }
selectHTML+= '</select>';
```

Now selectHTML is the variable containing the select pre created, you can now place it inside an HTML div by javascript or jquery. Hope i helped.

Answer (score 0):

I m asuming that you have the select on the body with a selector Id. If not you could create the select and then append this to the body.

```
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(json);
    var mySelect = $('#SelectorId');
     $.each(jsonData , function (index, item) {
        mySelect.append(
           $('<option>').text(item.pricebook_item)
                        .val(item.pricebook_item));
     });
```